# EF Don't save using IQueryable in BindingSource

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, binding

I've created a code first context with a DbSet property

I work with Windows form. If I bind as follow:

```
_context.Schedules.Load();
scheduleBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Schedules.Local.ToBindingList();
```

All works great and when I save as follow:

```
this.Validate();
scheduleBindingSource.EndEdit();
_context.SaveChanges();
```

The data persists; But when I bind the data like this:

```
var res = _context.Schedules.Where(k => k.EmployeeName.Equals(employeeComboBox.Text)).ToList();
scheduleBindingSource.DataSource = res;
```

When I save data doesn't persis!

I'm thinking that the ToList() method is not good, but I can't find alternative to get a BindingList connected to the Local set of data inside the context.

Thanks,

Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
_context.Schedules.Where(k => k.EmployeeName.Equals(employeeComboBox.Text)).Load();
scheduleBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Schedules.Local.ToBindingList();
```

That should only bring the schedules that meet the condition. When you call the `Load` method after the `Where` method, it is going to bring to memory only the records that meet the condition. Later, when you call the `Local` property,it will give you an `ObservableCollection<Schedule>` that contains all the objects that are currently tracked by the `DbContext` which thy are going to be the elements you loaded before. At the end, when you call the `ToBindingList` extension method, it will returns an `BindingList<Schedule>` that stays in sync with the given `ObservableCollection<Schedules>`.

Comment: I don't thik that it works because if I do Load() call don't replace _context.Schedules DbSet with a subset of data. As result I get the same racords that I have before the calling.

Comment: What call? Did you try the code I share in my answer? I do the same in my projects and it works, that only load the entities that meet the condition and not all the entities.

Comment: In the code of your answer using the method Where(...) you get an IQueryable object, after that you call .Load() on the IQueryable object, but you don't assign nothing to any variable.
When you call _context.Schedule.Local.ToBindingList() you don't get the result of the first line of code.

Comment: Check the Filtering section in this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/09/08/data-binding-with-dbcontext.aspx). The `Load` method can be used after LINQ operators

Comment: @AndreaPiovesan: octavioccl's suggestion also requires you to be using a new instance of `DbContext`. `Local` contains all entities that have been loaded into the context in the past, so if you've already used the context to view all `Schedules`, then `Local` will still contain all `Schedules`.

Comment: @jjj is right, if you loaded all the schedules and later you execute the code that I propose  using the same instance of your context, then you will get all the schedules because they were loaded previously, so you need to use a new instance of your context, and load only the schedules that meet the condition.

Comment: Ok, I get it, but...
Is correct that if I bind with BindingSource and ToList() method my data doesn't update?

Comment: Now I tried to use Filtering insted of query.. but BindingList does not support Filtering. It's a Nightmare!!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that caused the non-persistance of the data is caused by DataGridView (or the BindingSource), that don't add to context the new istance of the just added row.

So I've disabled the AllowUserToAddRow property (now I'm using BindingNavigator Add Button)

And implemented these two events as follow:

```
private void scheduleBindingSource_AddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    _scheduleAdding = true;
}

private void scheduleBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_scheduleAdding)
    {
        Schedule s = (Schedule)scheduleBindingSource.Current;
        s.EmployeeName = employeeComboBox.Text;
        s.From = new DateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.Year, dateTimePicker1.Value.Month, 1);
        _context.Schedules.Add(s);
        _scheduleAdding = false;
    }
}
```